# Not able to send data between UDP client in matlab and server in linux

Tags: c++, linux, matlab, sockets, udp

I have UDP program in matlab in one machine and UDP in cpp in other machine. I am able to send data from cpp code to matlab , by running cpp code as client and matlab code as server. When I tried running matlab as client and cpp as server I am  not able to send the data to cpp.In Both the above cases programms are running in two different machines.I tried matlab as client and cpp as server in same machine then its worked.

my cpp code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include "port.h"

#define BUFSIZE 2048

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_in myaddr;  /* our address */
    struct sockaddr_in remaddr; /* remote address */
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(remaddr);        /* length of addresses */
    int recvlen;            /* # bytes received */
    int fd;             /* our socket */
    unsigned char buf[BUFSIZE]; /* receive buffer */


    /* create a UDP socket */

    if ((fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("cannot create socket\n");
        return 0;
    }

    /* bind the socket to any valid IP address and a specific port */

    memset((char *)&myaddr, 0, sizeof(myaddr));
    myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    myaddr.sin_port = htons(SERVICE_PORT);

    if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&myaddr, sizeof(myaddr)) < 0) {
        perror("bind failed");
        return 0;
    }

    /* now loop, receiving data and printing what we received */
    for (;;) {
        printf("waiting on port %d\n", SERVICE_PORT);
        recvlen = recvfrom(fd, buf, BUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remaddr, &addrlen);
        printf("received %d bytes\n", recvlen);
        if (recvlen > 0) {
            buf[recvlen] = 0;
            printf("received message: \"%s\"\n", buf);
        }
    }
    /* never exits */
}
```

Comment: Do you have a firewall blocking the data going to the c++ server? That would explain it working on a single computer but not separate. If that isn't it, can you post the Matlab code as well?

Comment: matlab code [https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24525-a-simple-udp-communications-application]

Comment: I am able to send from cpp as client to matlab as server by running in different machine.

Comment: Do you get any socket errors? Or does it just sit in the recvfrom call? And have you tried running both the Matlab and c++ code on the Linux computer? If not, you could try running you c++ client code to test your c++ server

Comment: In any case, there is nothing obviously wrong with your code so I believe it is somehow related to your particular setup (I.e. a firewall like iptables).

Comment: okay .there is no socket error. it just sit on recvfrom call. This code is working in another linux machine.

Comment: I recommend two things: temporarily disable the firewall in Linux to be sure that isn't blocking the traffic (quick Google search gave me these instructions: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/turn-on-turn-off-firewall-in-linux/). Don't forget to to turn it back on when you're done. It is best to disconnect from the internet while it is off. Then use Wireshark (https://www.wireshark.org) to inspect the network traffic. Run Wireshark in the working setup to see what should happen, then run it in the broken setup for comparison. You could update your question with the Wireshark logs if you need help.

Comment: thank you. it worked when I enabled that port in firewall

Comment: Great, glad it works. If you feel your question was fully answered you can accept an answer to let other users know that this is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the answer from the comments here for visibility:

Since the programs work when run on the same computer, but not when run on separate computers, that points to a firewall issue (meaning the computer is blocking inbound traffic). In Linux, iptables (that's what the firewall is called) can be temporarily disabled per the instructions at: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/turn-on-turn-off-firewall-in-linux/

If that solves the problem, don't forget to turn iptables back on. Then just add an exception in iptables for your program similar to these instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#Allowing_Incoming_Traffic_on_Specific_Ports